# CREATE TABLE has no affect JBDC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So I'm learning about JBDC and I am trying to create a table through java. I have tested the user 'calgar' which can create a table through mysql commands however when I try to implement the same through java It has no affect.No Table created but no errors or exceptions also. Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null; 

        try{
            System.out.println("Connecting to driver/database..");
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/firstdatabase","calgar","password");
             System.out.println("Connection successful");
             statement = connection.createStatement();
             statement.execute("CREATE TABLE books(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100),author VARCHAR(100),publisher VARCHAR(100))");


        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException error){
            System.out.println("Class Not Found Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
       catch(SQLException error){
        System.out.println("SQL Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if(connection != null)
                try{connection.close();}
                catch(SQLException ignore){}

            if(statement != null)
                try{statement.close();}
                catch(SQLException ignore){}

        }
```

Comment: Try `statement.executeUpdate(sql);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use executeUpdate for database write operations

```
statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE ...");
```

Aside from that, use `PreparedStatement` to protect yourself from SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. what is the difference between execute and excuteUpdate?

Comment: Actually, `execute` is for when you don't know if there will be a result (and an update count is also a result) and what (and how many) results there are. There is no reason why a `CREATE TABLE` would fail with `execute()` and work with `executeUpdate()` for a driver following the specification.